# video won't start

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, video, gtk, totem

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I did a recent upgrade and my video won't start. The video window pops up with the correct video. It just never starts playing. Clicking play does nothing except turn the play button to a pause button (or visa versa). Meanwhile, no video plays. This is systemic. The same thing happens on totem, messenger, chrome, youtube, etc.

I've tracked down many useless paths. Right now I'm thinking possibly gtk related?

Any ideas would be appreciated!